# python scrapy images pipeline not downloading (301 error)

Tags: python, image, scrapy, http-status-code-301

I am trying to download images from pages like this on this site: http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru/miff39/eng/films/?id=39016. but i receive a 301 error and the images are not downloaded. i can download all my other data points without a problem, including `images_url`. (i am reusing scrapy code that has worked on other similar sites.) if i input the downloaded `images_url` into the browser, it returns a page with the image. however, the URL of the page is slightly different, a forward slash (`/`) is interpolated:

```
submit: http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru/upimg/cache/photo/640/6521.jpg
receive: http://moscowfilmfestival.ru/upimg//cache/photo/640/6521.jpg
```

the output log for the above page reads:

```
2018-01-02 11:19:40 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:62638/session/949ab9c1-6a0a-6a42-a19a-ef72c55acc33/url {"sessionId": "949ab9c1-6a0a-6a42-a19a-ef72c55acc33", "url": "http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru//miff39/eng/films/?id=39016"}

2018-01-02 14:46:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru//miff39/eng/films/?id=39016> (referer: None)

2018-01-02 14:46:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru/upimg/cache/photo/640/6521.jpg> (referer: None)
2018-01-02 14:46:59 [scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (code: 301): Error downloading file from <GET http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru/upimg/cache/photo/640/6521.jpg> referred in <None>
2018-01-02 14:46:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru//miff39/eng/films/?id=39016>
{'camera': ['HUANG LIAN'],
 'cast': ['GAO ZIFENG, MENG HALYAN, JHAO ZIFENG, HE MIAO, WAN PEILU'],
 'country': ['CHINA'],
 'design': ['YANG ZHIWEN'],
 'director': ['Liang Qiao'],
 'festival_edition': ['39th'],
 'festival_year': ['2017'],
 'image_urls': ['http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru/upimg/cache/photo/640/6521.jpg'],
 'images': [],
 'length': ['107'],
 'music': [''],
 'producer': ['DUAN PENG'],
 'production': ['SUNNYWAY FILM'],
 'program': ['Main Competition'],
 'script': ['LI YONG'],
 'sound': ['HU MAI, HAO CONG'],
 'synopsis': ['The story begins with Vince Kang, a reporter in Beijing, having '
              'to go back to his hometown to report a crested ibis, one of the '
              'national treasures found unexpectedly. During the process of '
              'pursuit and hide of the crested ibis, everyone’s interest is '
              'revealed and the scars, both mental and physical were rip up. '
              'In addition, the environment pollution, an aftermath from '
              'China`s development pattern, is brought into daylight. The '
              'story, from the perspective of a returnee, reveals the living '
              'condition of rural China and exposes the dilemma of humanity. '
              'In the end, Vince, the renegade, had no alternative but make a '
              'compromise with his birthland.'],
 'title': ['CRESTED IBIS'],
 'year': ['2017']}
```

to resolve the issue:

1. i have tried to mimic the browser url by interpolating the additional `/`. No effect.
2. i have tried to add a 301 exception handler to the spider class (`handle_httpstatus_all = True`) and also to the `settings.py` file. No effect.

interestingly, an earlier version of the spider i wrote completed a partial url mistakenly with an extra `/` (between the `.ru` and `miff` parts of the URL), and the `GET` and `POST` requests worked fine. they work just the same with the correct original page URL in the current version of the spider.

any help sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the urllib library to download any image.

```
import urllib
from urllib import request
url = 'http://39.moscowfilmfestival.ru/upimg/cache/photo/640/6521.jpg'
file_path = r'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/6521.jpg'
getPath, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_path)
print(getPath) #This is the image path
```

Comment: `urlretrieve(url, new_name)`

Comment: thanks for the help luca and furas! if i could upvote your answers i would. i'm still struggling a bit and would like to ask a couple of questions if i may. luca: if i run your code, 'getPath' is the path of the temporary file. furas: if, according to your suggestion, i add a value for the file name parameter of urlretrieve, luca's code returns the file name not a path. so, is there a way i can return the path to the local (not temp) folder? and name the file in the urlretrieve statement? thanks so much again!

Comment: @mnkhan I've just modified the answer, note: in file_path you have to include the entire file path, not just the file name

Comment: hi luca, if i didn't know the file path beforehand, would there be a way to obtain it using urlretrieve after the download, or would it be possible assign the file path somehow?

Comment: Yes, in `file_path` you can enter the path you prefer or you can empty file_path => `file_path = None'  and you'll obtain a randomic path in getPath